# "Public access is disabled. Please configure private endpoint." even though private endpoint configured for Azure OpenAI Service

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-openai, azure-private-dns-zone

I'm deploying Azure OpenAI Service via Terraform, and I want to set up a private endpoint for it. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-virtual-networks?tabs=portal) and [this article](https://blog.johnalfaro.com/blog/AOI#private-endpoint-for-open-ai-resource-) suggest that, besides a private endpoint, I need a private DNS zone containing an A record for the private endpoint.

It looks like this is not enough because I get the error "Public access is disabled. Please configure private endpoint." in Azure AI Studio when I test my GPT-35-turbo model.

[image]

Here's my Terraform code:

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  location = "westeurope"
  name     = "test-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_account" "openai" {
  name                          = "REDACTED"
  location                      = "westeurope"
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  kind                          = "OpenAI"
  sku_name                      = "S0"
  custom_subdomain_name         = "REDACTED"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "test-network"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  name                 = "test-private-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.1.1.0/24"]
  private_endpoint_network_policies_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  name                = "test-openai-private-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.private_subnet.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "test-openai-privconn"
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_cognitive_account.openai.id
    subresource_names              = ["account"]
    is_manual_connection           = false
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "openai" {
  name                = "privatelink.openai.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "openai" {
  name                = "test-openai-private-endpoint"
  zone_name           = "privatelink.openai.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 300
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "link" {
  name                  = "test-vnet-link"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.openai.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

resource "azurerm_cognitive_deployment" "model_gpt_35_turbo" {
  name                 = "test-gpt-35-turbo-model"
  cognitive_account_id = azurerm_cognitive_account.openai.id

  model {
    format  = "OpenAI"
    name    = "gpt-35-turbo"
    version = "0301"
  }

  scale {
    type = "Standard"
  }
}
```

**providers.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=0.12"

  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.64.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "REDACTED"
}
```

Additional info: I don't have any DNS server (the virtual network uses the default DNS server by Azure).

Answer (score 2):

> "Public access is disabled. Please configure private endpoint." even though private endpoint configured for Azure OpenAI Service.

I tried the same scenario in my environment and got the same result as you, even though I created the private endpoint in `OpenAI Studio`.

Disabled all networks and enabled **Private Endpoint**.

[image]

When I try to open the **Chat Service** in **OpenAI Studio** from another network, I also receive the same message.

[image]

You will encounter the above error even if you disable all networks under the `Firewall and Virtual Network` settings and create a `private endpoint` in **OpenAI Studio**.This confirms that the issue is not related to the configurations.

To test the connection, I created a virtual machine within the same `VNet` and tested the `Chat Service`. It is working as expected.

[image]

To create a private endpoint for `OpenAI Studio`, you need to integrate the private endpoint with a `Private DNS Zone`, as per microsoft's suggestion.

[image]

Reference: [DNS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-overview#dns-configuration)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! For clients outside the subnet, I found out I can whitelist their public IPs in Networking > Firewalls and virtual networks. This is not practical for a large number of clients with non-static IPs. Does Azure Open AI Studio support some kind of app gateway I can put in front so that I need to only whitelist the gateway's public IP?